# Unusual Behaviour of colon operator : in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, subset

```
2000:2017
```

The expected output is a vector of the sequence 2000 to 2017 with a step of 1.

Output: 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017

```
'2000':'2017'
```

However, when I type this command, it still gives me the same output.

Output: 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017

Unable to understand how it is generating sequence from characters.

**Edit 1:**

Ultimately, I am trying to understand why the code below worked? How can X2007:X2011 can possibly work? The select function is from dplyr package.

[R code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcSbJ.png)

My data also has similar column names as mentioned in the image above but I do not have 'X' there. I just have years like 2007,2008 etc.

For me select(Division, State, 2007:2011) does not work.

Error:Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Locations 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, and 2011 don't exist.

But this works select(Division, State, '2007':'2011').

Comment: You shouldn't edit your post to ask a completely different question after your first question has been answered. Just start a new post instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we check the more generic `seq.default`, it does changes the type from `character` to `numeric` for the `from` and `to`

```
...
if (!missing(from) && !is.finite(if (is.character(from)) from <- as.numeric(from) else from)) 
        stop("'from' must be a finite number")
    if (!missing(to) && !is.finite(if (is.character(to)) to <- as.numeric(to) else to)) 
...
```

Along on that lines, the documentation of `?:` also says so

> For other arguments from:to is equivalent to seq(from, to), and generates a sequence from from to to in steps of 1 or -1. Value to will be included if it differs from from by an integer up to a numeric fuzz of about 1e-7. Non-numeric arguments are coerced internally (hence without dispatching methods) to numeric—complex values will have their imaginary parts discarded with a warning.

---

Regarding the updated question with `subset` and `select`, if the column is numeric column name i.e. it starts with digit, it is an non-standard column name and evaluation of those can be done by backquoting

```
df1 <- data.frame(`2007` = 1:5, `2008` = 6:10, 
      `2012` =  11:15, v1 = rnorm(5), check.names = FALSE)
subset(df1, select = `2007`:`2012`)
#  2007 2008 2012
#1    1    6   11
#2    2    7   12
#3    3    8   13
#4    4    9   14
#5    5   10   15
```

Or with `dplyr::select`

```
library(dplyr)
select(df1, `2007`:`2012`)
#   2007 2008 2012
#1    1    6   11
#2    2    7   12
#3    3    8   13
#4    4    9   14
#5    5   10   15
```

If we have `X` at the beginning (happens when we read the data without `check.names = FALSE` - by default it is TRUE.  Or when we create the dataset with `data.frame` - here also the `check.names = TRUE` by default)

```
df1 <- data.frame(`2007` = 1:5, `2008` = 6:10, `2012` =  11:15, v1 = rnorm(5))
subset(df1, select = X2007:X2012)
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at Edit 1 also?

Comment: @AkhileshwarSharma the `select` does the range option with `:`. It finds the position of the column names and get the sequence from that position to the rhs name of `:`

Comment: So it must overload the `:` operator used in that position do something along the lines of `colnames(.)[grep(colnames(.)):grep(colnames(.)]`. It's probably not using `seq.default` on the character values.

Answer (score 2):

From what i know, `:` tries to coerce its 'arguments' to numeric, so that's why you got that output. Note that `"a":"b"` gives:

```
Error in "a":"c" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion 
2: NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at Edit 1 also?